# Need US passport while foreign consulate has it

Tags: visas, usa, passports

My two sons are studying abroad for four months beginning in January (one in Barcelona, Spain, and one in Prague, Czech Republic). It is now mid-October, and we are mailing their US passports to the Czech and Spanish embassies to obtain the visas that are required. Both indicate a 60-90 day turnaround to get the passports back.

We have a vacation planned for Mexico in late December. Any suggestions if mid-December comes and we haven't received the passports back yet from the respective embassy offices?

Comment: Do they offer an expedited-for-fee service?  That aside, 60-90 days is a long time.  If you're using a service, they may be able to give you more realistic times.

Comment: 60-90 Days may already be too late if they have to start in January. I Don't think you should opt for this standard service

Answer (score 4):

Apply for a second passport. You can utilize [this guide](http://www.us-passport-service-guide.com/second-passport.html)

You can utilize [US Passport Card](http://htps://travel.state.gov/content/studentsabroad/en/beforeyougo/passports/whatisapassportcardandhowtoapply.html), if you are going to be reentering US via land or sea.

Comment: Another option would be a passport card, which can be used for land crossings into both Canada and Mexico (but alas, not air travel).

Comment: Just checked and a PASSPORT CARD will NOT work as we are flying to and from Mexico.   Apparently, that's only for land and sea crossings.

Comment: Second Passport, then